# NSOutlineView: Why is shouldEditTableColumn: called twice?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

Hit enter for a row in my OutlineView, the shouldEditTableColumn method gets called twice. When I click to enter, it's called once.

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item{    
    NSLog(@"edit me");
    return YES;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be called any number of times. You can't rely on the number of times that it's called. `NSOutlineView` could choose to call it 50 times during one double click on your table instead of just once. This is true with just about any of the delegate methods. Regardless of how it works now, it could easily change in a future release as well.

Comment: What should I do to invoke a function from this method only once per click ?